# remove vector-elements from vector

Tags: r

This looks easy enough, but I keep bumping my head.

I have the numeric vector `v1`

```
v1 <- c(1,1,3,5,7,7)
```

And I have a numeric vector v2. **v2 is always a subset of v1**.
I want to remove the all elements from v2 from v1, but only *one*  (and exaclty one) v1 element per v2 element.

**desired output**

if `v2 <- c(3,5)` I want to keep `c(1,1,7,7)` from v1. This one is easy using `v1[-match(v2, v1)]`.
if `v2 <- c(1,7)` I want to keep `c(1,3,5,7)` from v1.  also, `v1[-match(v2, v1)]` does the trick.
if `v2 <- c(1,1)` I want to keep `c(3,5,7,7)` from v1. Now `v1[-match(v2, v1)]` returns `[1] 1 3 5 7 7`.. Not what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `vsetdiff` from the "vecsets" library (this will keep the duplicates as opposed to `setdiff`), in the following way:

```
library(vecsets)
v1 <- c(1,1,3,5,7,7)
v2.1 <- c(3,5)
> vsetdiff(v1, v2.1)
[1] 1 1 7 7
v2.2 <- c(1,7)
> vsetdiff(v1, v2.2)
[1] 1 3 5 7
v2.3 <- c(1,1)
> vsetdiff(v1, v2.3)
[1] 3 5 7 7
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to the `vecsets` package.. I can use those functions more often.

Comment: @Wimpel sure, its a useful package!

Comment: @DavidS Your `setdiff` approach seems not working giving `v2 <- c(1,3,7)`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding You are right, I didn't test it for more adge cases, it's strange as even `v2<-c(1,3)` doesnt work well. probably a bug.

Comment: You can keep the `vsetdiff` solution only, since I don't think `setdiff` can give a proper way to address this question. You can try `Map("*",1:5,c(-1,1))` to see how `Map` works. The case in your `setdiff` solution is just a very special case and works coincidently.

Answer (score 5):

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x[-match(y, x)], v2, init = v1)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's probably a better way using a truly recursive function, but I think you could accomplish this with a for loop:

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 7)
v2 <- c(1,1)
v1_keep <- v1

for (i in seq_along(v2)){
  v1_keep <- v1_keep[-match(v2[i], v1_keep)]
}

v1_keep
# [1] 3 5 7 7
```

Comment: I try to stay away from for-loops since production data is much larger than the samples given here. but still +1 for giving an answer that is providing the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(v1, v2, setdiff) %>% 
     flatten
```